# Trying to refer to columns in Excel using variables. What function should I use?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, variables

Trying to sort data in Excel alphabetically by row, but NOT in all of the columns for each row.
For example: Sort J7 through U7 alphabetically, then J8 through U8, all the way down through J2000 through U2000, while keeping each item within its row (like all cells in row 7 should still be in row 7 by the end of it.)

It seems like I'll need to use a macro/VBA for this, as Excel only lets you sort one row at a time alphabetically. If I select more than one row to sort, it still only sorts the first row.
I have done a bit of research as far as what kind of macros I could use for this, but nothing seems to do the job. The one thing I found that was similar to this sorts by number, but can't sort alphabetically.

Here's what I've got at a moment. I recorded a macro of myself selecting and sorting the row so that I could hopefully get all the code for that right at least:

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+j
'

Dim lngIndex As Long
Dim strArray(9 To 11000) As String
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim x As Integer
intCounter = 1
x = 9
For lngIndex = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
    intCounter = intCounter + 1
    strArray(lngIndex) = intCounter
    x = x + 1
    Range("Jx:UNx").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("export_729559 (3).xlsx").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("export_729559 (3).xlsx").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("Jx:UNx"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("export_729559 (3).xlsx").Sort
        .SetRange Range("Jx:UNx")
        .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

I'm getting: Run-time error ‘9’: Subscript out of range And it's highlighting the line: ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("export_729559 (3).xlsx").Sort.SortFields.Clear

I think the error I'm getting is because it's thinking I mean Column JX, rather than Column Jx, where x is a variable I was trying to use to cycle through each row. It seems like there are a few different ways to use variables instead of directly naming the columns, which I'll need to do to reference a new row through each iteration. Could someone recommend a certain function?

One of the ones I've come across is =OFFSET(), but I'm not sure if that would be a good fit for what I'm trying to do, and I'm having a hard time knowing how to fill it in with the right things.

Comment: You can specify a range numerically with e.g. Range(Cells(10,7),Cells(21,7)) which is equivalent to "J7:U7", it's just a pain referring to lettered columns by their number!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub Macro4()

Dim lngIndex As Long
Dim strArray(9 To 11000) As String
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet, rng As Range

Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("export_729559 (3).xlsx")
Set rng = sht.Range("J10:UN10")

intCounter = 1

For lngIndex = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)

    intCounter = intCounter + 1
    strArray(lngIndex) = intCounter

    With sht.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=rng, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
               Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange rng
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, it's giving me the same error with that code:
Run-time error ‘9’: Subscript out of range

But now it's highlighting this line:
    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("export_729559 (3).xlsx")

Is this potentially an issue with the name of my file?

Comment: I tried removing the space in the file name and updated my code accordingly, but it didn't fix the error.

Comment: If you get that error it's telling you there's no sheet with that name in the active workbook.  Copy the sheet name from the tab and paste it into your code: does it run then?

Comment: Ah okay, I changed the name of the workbook but not the sheet. Sorry, my first time doing something like this! Haha.

It didn't like the space, and I had to remove the parenthesis and the dot as well. I just renamed it Page1. Now it is running perfectly! Thanks! =)

Comment: Hey Tim, it turns out this worked perfectly except for one thing. The last cell of every row (some of which were in column 10, while others were in column 300) didn't get sorted, so instead of sorting cegdhbaf to abcdefgh, it sorts everything but except the f, which it leaves at the end where it was before, like this: abcdeghf

Do you know why that might be? If every row was the same length I'd think I had just not made my range big enough, but both my range and my strArray go far beyond the max length and width of my actual data.

Comment: If you sort those rows manually do they sort correctly?  And what's the purpose of `strArray` here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use x as a variable:

```
Range("J" & x & ":UN" & x)
```

If you put that in what you are using, should work.

Comment: Tried this one and got:
Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Select' of object 'Range' failed

I updated this line: Range("Jx:UNx").Select
with the below line, which is what's getting highlighted with the error 1004:
Range("J" & x & ":UN" & x).Select

Comment: Probably needs to be Activesheet.Range("J" & x & ":UN" & x).Select